# Is there popMatrix, pushMatrix, Translate in pygame?

Tags: python, canvas, graphics, pygame

Is there PopMatrix, PushMatrix, translate and/or rotate equivalent methods in pygame?

If not, what would be the challenges of developing them? And why don't they exist already?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you have working with something like fixed-function OpenGL before and you are asking for the equivalents for `glPushMatrix`, `glPopMatrix`, `glTranslate`, `glRotate`, etc in pygame?

Comment: Yes exactly, and it's not only in OpenGL, it's also in Processing and probably in many other languages that include graphic design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing the matrix stack to keep track of your transformations would be relatively simple. Here is a simple class I made (have not double-checked this code for errors) that replicates a lot of the functionality you would see in something like you might find in [Processing's API reference](https://processing.org/reference/) (look under the **Transform** section):

**matstack.py**

```
import math
import numpy as np

_stack = [np.identity(4)]

def apply_mat(mat):
    _stack[-1] = np.dot(_stack[-1], mat)

def pop_mat():
    _stack.pop()

def push_mat():
    _stack.append(get_mat())

def get_mat():
    return _stack[-1]

def reset_mat():
    _stack[-1] = np.identity(4)

def rotate_mat(radians):
    c = math.cos(radians)
    s = math.sin(radians)
    rotate = np.array([
        [c, s, 0, 0],
        [-s, c, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
    ], dtype=np.float32)
    apply_mat(rotate)

def translate_mat(x_shift, y_shift):
    x, y = x_shift, y_shift
    translate = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [x, y, 0, 1],
    ], dtype=np.float32)
    apply_mat(translate)

def scale_mat(x_scale, y_scale):
    x, y = x_scale, y_scale
    scale = np.array([
        [x, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, y, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
    ], dtype=np.float32)
    apply_mat(scale)
```

Usage of this class is pretty simple too:

**main.py**

```
import math
import matstack as ms

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ms.reset_mat()
    ms.translate_mat(rect.x, rect.y)
    ms.rotate_mat(math.radians(45))
    ms.scale_mat(2, 0.5)
    print(ms.get_mat())
```

The problem, however, is in deciding how we apply these matrices so that they **actually affect the drawing of surfaces in pygame**. The problem is that everything in pygame revolves around the lowly `pygame.Rect` object. If we take a look at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), we find that a `pygame.Rect` constructor is of the form `Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect`. This means that fundamentally, `pygame.Rect` must be an **Axis-aligned minimum bounding box (AABB)** whose edges must always parallel `x = 0` and `y = 0`. This has many useful properties (see all of those helper functions in the documentation!), but ultimately prevents complex transformations like rotation.

As to *why* this is the case, I believe this can be attributed to the parent technology that pygame relies on, which is [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), specifically the (outdated) SDL 1.2. While something like Processing (which likely relies on OpenGL) uses hardware acceleration for its drawing (passing 4x4 matrices alike to the GPU and performing super-fast transformations), SDL 1.2 is a software renderer that was not designed with GPUs in mind. Since the GPU cannot be used to perform the transformations, the work must be done at the CPU level, manipulating and "blitting" boxes of pixels to get the desired effects.

To get around this limitation, SDL has a module, SDL_gfx, which is likely what pygame uses under-the-hood for its `pygame.transform` module. This can handle several fixed options, like rotation and scaling, using built-in functions. However, these functions just return `Surface` objects containing the newly-transformed pixels. Therefore, there is nowhere in the pipeline to pass in our matrices!

**If you really need matrices and stacks in your application**, I would suggest working with OpenGL using `PyOpenGL`. You could then use the fixed function (terribly out-of-date by the way) matrix stack operations which I talked about in the comment on your question. You can use pygame still in this process to manage the window and input.

If you particularly just want something inspired by Processing but for python that *already takes this approach*, I found [this p5 library](https://github.com/p5py/p5) while I was searching online. If you just want to use the Processing ecosystem, but with "python" syntax (implemented in Java), [python-mode](https://github.com/jdf/processing.py#python-mode-for-processing) might be the better option. Hopefully this gives you some insight into this problem and some possible solutions!

Comment: [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) seems to be a nice alternative to PyOpenGL. I've only experimented a little bit with it, but it looks pretty cool. For some of the examples they use the matrix types in the [pyrr](https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/Pyrr) library.

Comment: @skrx Wow, that does look a very clean API! I will check it out. I hope it plays nice with my cython stuff, since I noticed that ModernGL apparently uses some C++ stuff at its core to speed up some operations (which is definitely an issue with PyOpenGL. It is definitely nice to have something else to recommend now instead, though!